# How to inner join with 3 request on the same table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to join 3 results of 3 differents requests on the same table :

My table :

```
TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG
    DATE_VOL
    NUMERO_VOL
    CODE_CLIENT
    SITE_PROD
    CODE_CLASSE
    STATUT_FIAB
    CENTRE_PROFIT
    TYPE_CA
    MONTANT_QUOD
    MONTANT_RISTOURNE
    MONTANT_AN
    MONTANT_TOT_QUOD
    MONTANT_TOT_MENS
    MONTANT_TOT_AN
    DATE_CHGT
```

My request :

```
SELECT * FROM (

        SELECT
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL AS DATE_VOL,
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL,
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT,
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD,
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE,
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT,
          sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD),
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB,
          sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_RISTOURNE)
        FROM
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG
        WHERE
          (
           TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL  <=  trunc(sysdate)-2
           AND
           TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'MM'))  =  CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '1' OR TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '2' THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))-1
        ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))
        END
           AND
           To_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'SYYYY'))  =  CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')) = '1' THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))-1
        ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))
        END
           AND
           TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD  <>  'LAT'
          )
        GROUP BY
          TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE, 
        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB
        ORDER BY   TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL ASC
)  CTE1
INNER JOIN (

    select *  FROM
    (

                      SELECT
                       -- TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'MM')),
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL AS DATE_VOL,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT,
                        sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD),
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB
                      FROM
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG
                      WHERE
                      ( TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=2  )
                        AND  
                        (
                         TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL  <=  trunc(sysdate)-2
                         AND
                         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'MM'))  =  CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '1' OR TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '2' THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))-1
                      ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))
                      END
                         AND
                         To_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'SYYYY'))  =  CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')) = '1' THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))-1
                      ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))
                      END
                         AND
                         TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD  <>  'LAT'
                        )
                      GROUP BY
                       -- TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'MM')), 
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL, 
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL, 
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT, 
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD, 
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE, 
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT, 
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB
                                   )CTE2
                    INNER JOIN( 
                     SELECT
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL AS DATE_VOL,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE,
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT,
                        sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD),
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB
                      FROM
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG
                      WHERE
                      ( TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=1  )
                        AND  
                        (
                         TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL  <=  trunc(sysdate)-2
                         AND
                         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'MM'))  =  CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '1' OR TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '2' THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))-1
                      ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))
                      END
                         AND
                         To_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'SYYYY'))  =  CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')) = '1' THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))-1
                      ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))
                      END
                         AND
                         TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD  <>  'LAT'


                        )
                      GROUP BY
                        TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE, 
                      TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT, TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB
                      ORDER BY 
                      TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL) CTE3
                      ON CTE2.DATE_VOL = CTE3.DATE_VOL ) CTE4
 ON CTE1.DATE_VOL=CTE4.DATE_VOL;
```

The problem is : I don't know how to join my two groups CTE1 & CTE4. ( at the end of my request )

```
 ON CTE2.DATE_VOL = CTE3.DATE_VOL ) CTE4
     ON CTE1.DATE_VOL=CTE4.DATE_VOL;
```

**More informations** :

The only difference between these 3 requests is :
 `( TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=2  )` in the WHERE condition, who gives me a different result for : `sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD)`

I want to join for the same :

```
DATE_VOL
NUMERO_VOL
CODE_CLIENT
SITE_PROD
CODE_CLASSE
STATUT_FIAB
CENTRE_PROFIT
```

the result of   `sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD)` with

`( TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=2  )` **AND** `(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=1  )` **AND** 
without this condition.

- CTE1 is my biggest request ( got all flights )
- CTE4 = CTE2 & CTE3
- CTE1 = NO CONDITION ON STATUT_FIAB
- CTE2 = ( TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=2  )
- CTE3 = ( TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=1  )

Thank you a lot for any information.

Comment: Can you elaborate what DATE_VOL is and what flights you are looking for?

Comment: DATE_VOL is the date of my flight. I want all flights in the final result

Comment: Couldn't you just join CTE1 with CTE2 and CTE3? Why do you need CTE4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, do you really need joins here? Or could you just compute the sums with subqueries like this:

```
SELECT
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL AS DATE_VOL,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT,
    sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD) AS sum_all,
    sum(case when TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=1 then TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD else 0 end) AS sum_fiab_1,
    sum(case when TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB=2 then TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_QUOD else 0 end) AS sum_fiab_2,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB,
    sum(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.MONTANT_RISTOURNE)
FROM
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG
WHERE (
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL <= trunc(sysdate)-2
    AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'MM')) = CASE
        WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '1' OR TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD')) = '2'
        THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))-1
        ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM'))
    END
    AND To_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,'SYYYY')) = CASE
        WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM')) = '1'
        THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))-1
        ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'SYYYY'))
    END
    AND TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD  <>  'LAT'
)
GROUP BY
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.NUMERO_VOL,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLIENT,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.SITE_PROD,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CODE_CLASSE,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.CENTRE_PROFIT,
    TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.STATUT_FIAB
ORDER BY
     TB_DW_CA_DETAIL_AGG.DATE_VOL ASC
```

Comment: You are right, I don't need Join my results here. I do joins all day, I do not even think with other things...
Thank you a lot !!

Comment: Glad to help :)